# Is there a similar application to "Google Authenticator app" for ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I have enabled two step verification on my Dropbox, Facebook and Google accounts and I had Google Authenticator installed on my mobile phone, in order to be able to log in my accounts.

However, now my mobile phone has a problem, and I cannot use that on my mobile. Is there any similar app that can be installed on Ubuntu and do the same job?

Answer (score 2):

There are many implementations to two factor authentication app[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator)

I found a ruby implementation **twofu** helpful
You can install it by

```
$sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration

$sudo gem install twofu
```

[twofu github page](https://github.com/ukazap/twofu)

It is not recommended and it defeats the purpose of 2 factor authentication but I lost access to  neteller accout after I flashed a rom on my phone and I also fear I could loose my phone so I started searching for desktop app.